# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized):

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, setcookie

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    require('dotenv').config();
}

// Libraries:
const express = require('express');
const app = express();     //
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const cors = require('cors');

// Models:
const User = require('./models/users');

// Environment variables:
const jwtSecret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
const dbUrl = process.env.DB_URL || 'mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/chatapp';

// Database connection
mongoose.connect(dbUrl)
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Database Connected");
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("MONGO CONNECTION ERROR!!!");
        console.log(err);
    })

//
const corsOption = {
    origin: ['http://localhost:3001'],
    credentials: true,
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
}

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    next();
});
app.use(cors());
// app.use(cors());


// Routes 
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hi');
});

app.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
    const token = req.cookies?.token;
    console.log(req.cookies);
    if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret, {}, (err, userData) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.status(401).json("Token verification failed");
            };

            // console.log(userData);

            res.json(userData);
            console.log(userData);
        });
    } else {
        res.status(401).json("no token");
        console.log('No token');
    }
});

app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    // console.log(req.body);
    const { username, email, password } = req.body;
    console.log(username, email, password);
    try {
        const registeredUser = await User.create({ username, email, password });
        jwt.sign({ userId: registeredUser._id, username }, jwtSecret, {}, (err, token) => {
            if (err) throw err; // show only message in the production
            res.cookie('token', token, { sameSite: 'none', secure: true }).status(201).json({
                id: registeredUser._id,
            });
        });
    } catch (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.status(500).json('error');
        // console.log(err);
    }
});



app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log("Serving on port 3001!");
})
```

this is code for **App.js on server side**

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import Body from './components/Body'
import axios from 'axios';
import { UserContextProvider } from './contexts/UserContext';

function App() {
  axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3001';
  // axios.defaults.withCredentials = true; // so that we can set cookies from our api

  return (
    <UserContextProvider>
        <Body/>
    </UserContextProvider>
  )
}

export default App
```

This is **App.jsx on client side**

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import Register from './Register';
import { userContext } from '../contexts/UserContext';

const Body = () => {

    const { username, id } = useContext(userContext);

    if(username){
        return 'loged in!';
    }

    return (
        <Register />
    );
};

export default Body;
```

code for **Body.jsx on client side**

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { userContext } from '../contexts/UserContext';

const Register = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        username: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
    });

    const { setUsername, setId, setCookie } = useContext(userContext);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        setState({
            ...state,
            [e.target.name]: value
        });
    };

    const handleRegistration = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const userData = {
            username: state.username,
            email: state.email,
            password: state.password,
        };
        // console.log(userData);
        await axios.post("/register", userData, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
            .then((response) => {
                // console.log(response);
                // console.log(data.id);
                setUsername(state.username);
                setId(response.data.id);
                // this.props.history.push(from.pathname)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        // console.log(username, email, password);


    };

    return (
        <div className='d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center' >
            <div className='' style={{ width: "50%", marginTop: "10%" }}>
                <h1 className='mb-3'>Register</h1>
                <form className="" onSubmit={handleRegistration} noValidate>
                    <div className="mb-3">
                        <label className="form-label" htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                        <input className="form-control" type="text" id="username" name="username" value={state.username} onChange={handleChange} required />
                    </div>
                    <div className="mb-3">
                        <label className="form-label" htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                        <input className="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" value={state.email} onChange={handleChange} required />
                    </div>
                    <div className="mb-3">
                        <label className="form-label" htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                        <input className="form-control" type="password" id="password" name="password" value={state.password} onChange={handleChange} required />
                    </div>
                    <button type='submit' className="btn btn-success w-100">Register</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Register;
```

Code for **Register.jsx on client side**

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


export const userContext = createContext({});

export const UserContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState(null);
    const [id, setId] = useState(null);
    // const [cookie, setCookie] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        // const fetchData = async () => {
        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: '/profile',
        })
            .then(response => {
                // Handle the response
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                // Handle errors
                console.error(error);
            });
    }, []);

    return (
        <userContext.Provider value={{ username, setUsername, id, setId }}>
            {children}
        </userContext.Provider>
    )

}
```

code for **UserContext.jsx on client side**

I am successfullly able to register new user but when I am trying to access the userData using a get request on 'http://localhost:3001/profile'.

The client side is not able to send cookie along with the get request to the server side and due to that I am getting error:
'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)'

**Axios Error:**

```
{
    "message": "Request failed with status code 401",
    "name": "AxiosError",
    "stack": "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401\n    at settle (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=034a35d4:1204:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=034a35d4:1421:7)",
    "config": {
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        },
        "adapter": [
            "xhr",
            "http"
        ],
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1,
        "env": {},
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
        },
        "baseURL": "http://localhost:3001",
        "method": "get",
        "url": "/profile"
    },
    "code": "ERR_BAD_REQUEST",
    "status": 401
}
```

I tried to get the user data through get request but while making the request the client side is not sending any cookie to the server side and due to this the request is not authorised.